# form validation using oop php

Tags: php, oop

I want to validate a form using php by object oriented technique. I created a class validator by watching a tutorial but I want to add more rules in this class such as regular expressions and a number check and email check. Also the password must be eight to five characters in length with one being upper case and one lower case etc. But I can't add more rules in this class.

> I added a max length rule but it is not working.

```
<?php 
class Validator {
    // for form fields storing
    private $fields = array();
    //for storing errors for form fields
    private $field_errors = array();
     private $form_is_valid = true;

    public function add_field($field_name){
        $this->fields[]= $field_name;
        //associative array6
        $this->field_errors[$field_name] = array();
    }
    public function add_rule_to_field( $field_name, $field_rule){
        $rule_name = $field_rule[0];



        switch ($rule_name)
        {
            case 'min_length':
                if (strlen($_POST[$field_name]) < $field_rule[1]){
                    $this->add_error_to_field($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " cannot be less than {$field_rule[1]} in length");
                    //echo "must 1 chr <br>";
                }
            break;
            case 'empty':
                if(strlen($_POST[$field_name]) == 0){
                    $this->add_error_to_field($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " cannot be empty");
                    //echo "not empty <br>";
                }
            break;
            case 'max_legnth':
                if(strlen($_POST[$field_name]) > $field_rule[2]){
                    $this->add_error_to_field($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " cannot be greater then {$field_rule[2]} in length");
                }
            break;
            default:
            break;
        }
    }
    private function add_error_to_field($field_name, $error_message){
        $this->form_is_valid = false;
        $this->form_is_valid ;
        $this->field_errors[$field_name][] = $error_message;
        //echo "add error to filed is working <br>";
    }
    public function form_valid(){
        return $this->form_is_valid;
    }
    public function out_field_error($field_name){
        if (isset($this->field_errors[$field_name])){
            //echo "out ";
            foreach ($this->field_errors[$field_name] as $field_errors){
                echo "<p class='error'> {$field_errors} </p>";
                //echo "out is running";
            }
        }
    }


}
 ?>
```

> Here is my form and object instance of the class:

```
<?php 

      require_once('validator.php');
      $validator = new Validator;

      if(isset($_POST['submit'])){
            $validator->add_field('name');
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('name', array('min_length', 5));
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('name', array('empty'));

            $validator->add_field('email');
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('email', array('min_length', 6));
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('email', array('empty'));

            $validator->add_field('number');
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('number', array('min_length', 8));
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('number', array('empty'));
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('number', array('max_length', 10));

            $validator->add_field('password');
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('password', array('min_length', 8));
            $validator->add_rule_to_field('password', array('empty'));

            $validator->filed_out();


            if ($validator->form_valid() == true){
                  echo " registration is sucessfull";

                  exit();
            }
            // else{
            //       echo "form is not valid";
            //      //exit();
            // }

}

 ?>





<form method="POST" id="form-add" action="">
            <label>Name:</label>
            <input type="text" name="name" value=""/>
            <span> <?php $validator->out_field_error('name'); ?></span>

            <label>Email:</label>
            <input type="text" name="email" value=""/>
            <span><?php $validator->out_field_error('email'); ?></span>

            <label>Number:</label>
            <input type="text" name="number" value=""/>
            <span><?php $validator->out_field_error('number'); ?></span>

            <label>Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="password" value=""/>
            <span><?php $validator->out_field_error('password'); ?></span>

            <label>Re Enter Password:</label>
            <input type="text" name="cpassword" value=""/>
            <span></span>

            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="SUBMIT"/>
        </form>
```

Comment: @Sean about your edit https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/18976520 please, don't use blockquotes for this. it's text. Edit: I took those out. This could be flaggable for moderation btw.

Comment: What do you mean by _"But I can't add more rules in this class."_?

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner, For some reason the IOS app of stackoverflow added blockquotes to the revision. I fixed it in a newer edit, thanks for the feedback.

Comment: @Sean That's rather odd about the IOS doing that. As for your fixing it; actually the 2 lines of "text" are in blockquotes.

Comment: @Funk Forty Niner That is odd indeed, I do not see any blockquotes in the current revision of this post. Does it still appear for you?

Comment: @Sean Both `I added a max length rule but it is not working` and `Here is my form and object instance of the class:` have that "banner effect" because of the `>` characters before them. This being on a PC, I don't have IOS. Maybe something that could be posted on meta as a bug, but TBH; I won't bother since I can't reproduce it.

Comment: I just hopped on PC and I see the same > before the two lines. Doesn't show up on my stackoverflow IOS app though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- The `$rule_name` in the switch case is `"max_legnth"` but should be `"max_length"`. So you never fall in this case.
- Your "max_length" rule use the index 2, instead of the index 1, because `$field_rule` is defined as `array('max_length', 10)`. So you have an *"undefined index"* notice.

The code of the rule :

```
        case 'max_length':
            if(strlen($_POST[$field_name]) > $field_rule[1]){
                $this->add_error_to_field($field_name, ucwords($field_name). " cannot be greater then {$field_rule[1]} in length");
            }
            break;
```